# Linq join query error

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to join multiple datatables to create a single datatable. Here is the query.

```
var row = from r0w1 in dt_vi.AsEnumerable()
          join r0w2 in dt_workcenter.AsEnumerable()
          on r0w1.Field<int>("wcID") equals r0w2.Field<int>("iD")
          join r0w3 in dt_recipe.AsEnumerable()
          on r0w1.Field<int?>("curingRecipeID") equals r0w3.Field<int?>("recipe_id") join r0w4 in dt_defect.AsEnumerable()
          on r0w1.Field<int?>("defectID") equals r0w4.Field<int?>("defect_id") into ps
          from r0w4 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select r0w1.ItemArray.Concat(r0w2.ItemArray.Concat(r0w3.ItemArray.Concat(r0w4.ItemArray))).ToArray();

foreach (object[] values in row)
    dt.Rows.Add(values);
```

I tried to join r0w1 & r0w4 as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. But here I am getting the error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Error seems to be in

```
r0w4.ItemArray
```

May be r0w4 is not getting any value. What could be the possible reason ?

Comment: _May be r0w4 is not getting any value._ .... and have you checked that?

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` returns `null` if join fails, so you cannot directly rely on data in that object. You may need to do a null check

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `ps.DefaultIfEmpty()` will return the default value (`null` in this case) when no row match and thus it is throwing that error.

You can change it like this:-

```
r0w3.ItemArray.Concat(r0w4 != null ? r0w4 .ItemArray : new object[] {}))
```